# Which visualisation software for a layered graph?

Tags: visualization

I have produced a CSV file in the following format:

```
position number | list of positions it links to | 2nd list of positions it links to | ... | 6th list of positions it links to
```

All the items are integers and the lists are of varying size.

The file forms a kind of tree or web (it's a game tree).

I would like to visualise the data as a web or tree.

I can sort the tree according to distance from opening move (another integer), but maybe I won't need to.

I would like it to look something like this:

```
1
| \
2  4
|\ |\
3,7,5,9
......
....
|/
2000
```

Any ideas on what software I should use and a few hints?

Comment: Could you post a few lines of data inline or a link to a full file using https://gist.github.com/, http://pastebin.com/, or the likes

Comment: Hi there Max, I have put the data in the form of a list of edges and visualised using gelphi. This seemed to work well.

Answer (score 4):

You would need to change the output format, but this sort of data (a layered graph) works well with [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/), specifically [dot](http://www.graphviz.org/content/dot-language).

Answer (score 0):

A guess would be [Cytoscape](http://www.cytoscape.org/) - I haven't used it in anger but I helped someone look into it for something else and what I saw was promising